# How to proper handle NotAuthorizedException in AWS

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito

The AWS Cognito [InitiateAuth](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.initiate_auth) can throw the NotAuthorizedException if something fails during login.

The problem that I'm facing is that the exception can be thrown by the client for multiple reasons:

- wrong password
- temporary password expired
- etc

but it's seems that there's no specific exception thus the only way i see for properly handle this it's to check the returned message

```
{'Error': {'Code': 'NotAuthorizedException',
           'Message': 'Temporary password has expired and must be reset by an '
                      'administrator.'},
...
```

Is this the correct way? because it seems very shaky to test the Message string (that is supposed to be changed from the sdk for whatever reason since it's just a display message).

In the end i would like to being able to understand if the user just sent a wrong authentication data or if its temporary password password it's completely "broken" and should be resetted

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed how the error response is structured. Kind of silly but there does not seem to be a better way to handle this than to string match the error message text.

Seems like an oversight from the Cognito team.