# Is there any way to handle Cognito Tempory password expiry, since incorrect credentials also has the same type of response

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

After generating a temporary password for a new user in Amazon Cognito, it is sent to the provided Email with a specified expiry period. However, when attempting to log in using the initiateAuth method, there is no apparent distinction between using an expired temporary password or an incorrect credential. Both scenarios result in the same statusCode and Exception type, with the only difference being the error message. Therefore, I would like to inquire if there is a way to differentiate between these two cases.

```
statusCode: 400
ExceptionType: NotAuthorizedException
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the `Message` attribute which will contain the text: `"Temporary password has expired and must be reset by an administrator."`

Unfortunately there is no way to distinguish this error from other unauthorized reasons (which should really be status code 401). See [How to proper handle NotAuthorizedException in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69276493/how-to-proper-handle-notauthorizedexception-in-aws/77356488#77356488).